# Client side validation seems to fire even when disabled under ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We have an ASP.Net MVC3 app which is to be used in the UK and Germany.

Some of the edit screens involve editing floating point values.  These are presented using

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Multiplier, new { size = 5, id = "multiplier" })
```

...or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Multiplier, new { size = 5, id = "multiplier" })
```

Our basic problem is that when running with a culture of DE-de (which uses , for decimal point) we get messages in the validation summary saying things like

> •The value '4,3' is not valid for Multiplier.

On doing a bit of research I found that internationalisation support for client side validation isn't that great in MVC 3.  I understand that there are potential solutions involving adding more recent Javascript globalization efforts.  But in order to minimize the impact I would rather simply disable client side validation and accept that this validation will need to be done on the server side.

So... I attempted to disable client side validation in a number of ways:

a) In the code of the edit screen:

```
@using Foo.Models.Analyses
@model Foo.Models.Analyses.Bar
@{ 
    Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(false);

    using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" }))
   {
```

b)  As above but using the syntax HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false; HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false

c)  As in a) and b) but using web.config.

None of these seems to suppress the messages.  So my questions are:

1) Which part of the framework is still performing this validation.  (It isn't happening in the server side Validate overrides.)

2) How do I suppress this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the jquery.validate javascript from being rendered by the client?

Comment: Thanks @Mystere Man.  How would I suppress that other than through the Html.Enable... calls?  Many thanks.

Comment: As I said, by removing the jquery.validate javascript from the rendered page.  You just remove the reference.

Comment: Are you still getting hidden inputs with the validation messages in your output? That is where the validation text is typically placed. I added `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;` into my `Application_Start()` and they were removed completely. Were your web.config changes correct? Also make sure you have no `ValidationFor` calls in your views (often generated by the wizards).